# use of "den" instead of "der" in "Sie geben den Schülern Hausaufgaben."

Tags: dative

In the sentence

> Sie geben den Schülern Hausaufgaben.

i.e. **They're giving the students homework**

I know that any plural in German is given the feminine article "die" but if "die" becomes "der" in the dative (noting that Schülern is dative above)

*Why is the sentence not written as*

> Sie geben der Schülern Hausaufgaben.

Comment: http://canoo.net/inflection/sch%C3%BCler:N:M

Comment: I recommend to change the mental image: *die* is not **the** feminine article, but a word, which can be feminie singular or masculine/neuter plural article.

Comment: https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/der#Artikel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, we're having a plural form here, and »den« is the dative article in plural.

So be aware of *singular* vs *plural* articles, and also note that the article »die« has multiple functions, among them *nom. (and acc.) fem. sg. article*, but also *nom. pl. article* in any gender. Thus:

- »die Schülerin» (»the female student«, *fem. sg.*) becomes »der Schülerin« in dative. So »They're giving homework to the female student« is translated »Sie geben der Schülerin Hausaufgaben.«
- By contrast, »die Schüler« (note the missing »in«) is the plural of »der Schüler« and becomes »den Schülern« in dative. So even though the nominative article again is »die«, this time it's *masc. pl.*, and so the dative is »den«. That's why »Sie geben den Schülern Hausaufgaben« is indeed correct.